# Silverlight - TextWrapping WordEllipsis not working within Grid with no fixed width

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

The following grid and container(s) do not have a fixed width.

I'm trying to force the text within TextBlock controls to be trimmed with an ellipsis.

The text is not trimmed, instead the entire text is displayed which goes outside the width of the silverlight application.

The issue seems to be related to the fact there is no fixed width for the grid or it's container(s).  As soon as I configure a width, the text is trimmed as desired.

Has anyone experienced this issue?  Is there a way of getting the text to trim?

Thanks in advance.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="ExampleTemplate">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Long text here - blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Long text here - blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Long text here - blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>        
</UserControl.Resources>

<ScrollViewer>
  <ItemsControl  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ExampleTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding ExampleRows}"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought you could get the text to trim as the trimming will require a known width to trim to.

Comment: The width of the grid columns is defined using percentages 30%, 30%, 40% in my above example.  If the columns contain a small amount of text, the columns scale according to the size of the application - the grid must know its width to be able to scale the columns accordingly?  Therefore, I'd expect the TextBlock to inherit the columns width.

Comment: I have tried your code and it works fine, may be there are more elements in your XAML? If yes please give all XAML.

Comment: @Samvel Siradeghyan - Problem solved, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The ScrollViewer 'HorizontalScrollBarVisibility' property was set to 'Hidden', the property should have been set to 'Disabled'.

Thanks.